# Using the loop cut and adding additional loops

Tags: modeling, loop

I have an issue with loop cut. It says press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and then you can use the mouse wheel to adjust the cuts. I am using industry standard keys and <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is the shortcut but middle mouse button only zooms.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: after you have pressed alt c and before doing anything else then roll your mouse wheel. So you will get the first loop cut showing, at that point roll the wheel.

Comment: Yep, absolutely nothing before scrolling, just zooms the window

Comment: Are you seeing the [yellow line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk0gm.png) in loop cut mode? You have to hover over the geometry with your mouse.

Comment: OK, I have tried all of these and none work. I use the Industry shortcuts that make loop cut to alt C. the only think that the middle mouse does is zoom, the middle click doesn't seem to do anything either.
I can use the tool after to add segments but would be nice for it to work the same way Max does as it give you a small gui to control the tool before.

Thanks

PS I have tried with 2.8 and 2.81

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morning all.

Ok, I have found a sort of fix. If I use the right click menu on edge select and use that loop and drag tool, it works as to be expected but not if I use the side menu or shortcut

Thanks for everyone's input though, I'll get it logged as a bug as im trying out 2.81

Many thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ALT</kbd> **+** <kbd>C</kbd> does not make **ZOOM** this only centers the model on the 3D viewPort

[image]

### on the other hand perhaps what you are looking for is the following

[image]

### unless you refer to

<kbd>ALT</kbd> **+** <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> **+** <kbd>C</kbd>

[image]